# Occasional "SMTP server requires a secure connection" from ASP.NET SmtpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I have a ASP.NET web app that sends emails, usually in response to an action from a mobile app posting to a WebAPI. Sometimes (e.g. today it happened 4 times, but it hasn't done it in weeks), it refused to send a few emails with the following error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException  [The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
>   was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail

Why would it only do this occasionally? I am currently going through and ensuring the `SmtpClient` is being disposed (no disposal in current code) - could that be the cause?

Here's my set-up code:

```
        smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587)
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            EnableSsl = true,
            Timeout = 30000,
        };

        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]);
```

Other than disposing the SmtpClient object is there anything else I ought to do to avoid the message? Where else should I look? Thanks peops.

Comment: I have no idea what's causing this. But if it's intermittent, you should look into using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). You could write a retry strategy. Perhaps retry after 1 second, 10 seconds, 30 seconds, 90 seconds. If none of those attempts work, then actually let the exception bubble up. Even if you weren't getting this particular error, it's a good idea. Could help you through temporary server glitches or connectivity issues.

Comment: I am catching the exception and (ironically) emailing to me so I see them. It's plausible some of these are failing to so I only see some of the errors ... !!! eek. 
Is that what you mean by letting the exception bubble up?

Comment: Wow, polly looks pretty awesome!

Comment: I mean let it bubble up to your error handling layer. Emailing isn't a good form of error handling. Look into libraries like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) and [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), combined with somewhere to store the log events such as [Seq](https://getseq.net/).